# How can I disable ListView overscrolling in Android 2.2?

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView that's overscrolling even though the items displayed are not larger than what can fit on the screen.

On Android 2.3 and up, once can use ListView#setOverScrollMode(int) to prevent a ListView from overscrolling, but how would you do this on 2.2?

Clarification: this is not happening on stock android devices, it has been observed on a Samsung TouchWiz device running Android 2.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is Samsung UI customization and I don't know it can be disabled easily.